# How can I get a complex LINQ query to work where I need to check by two elements and an attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to get a LINQ query to work by finding the Login information from an XML file where the parent has an attribute of type and I want the values of the elements underneath them.  So without the XML tags what I have is:

```
Users
   Username type=Test
      Login testuser1
      Password password
   Username type=Test2
      Login testuser2
      Password password
```

Since I will need to pull many of these values out I'd like a function where I can give it a type tag and have the correct value of the Login name returned, I've tried this a couple of different ways and haven't gotten LINQ to do what I want.  I'm probably missing something but I am trying to go by the Microsoft examples, and some others but I haven't found anything quite like what I am trying to do to go by.  I learn best by example and testing and so far I haven't gotten anything to work right.

I have tried two different versions of this:

```
public string getTestUserInfo(string type)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(type);
        XElement root = XElement.Load("TestInformation.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> myusername = 
            from el in root.Elements("Username")
            where (string)el.Attribute("Type") == type
            select el.Element("Login");
        string username = myusername.ToString();
        return username;
    }
```

Which I was hoping would return the Username of type Test or Test2 depending on what I sent, then return me the el.Value of Login.  I can't seem to get the syntax right to get the value.  I also tried:

```
Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(type);
XElement root = XElement.Load("TestInformation.xml");
string username = (string)
    (from el in root.Elements("Username")
     where (string)el.Attribute("Type") == type
     select el.Element("Login"));
return username;
```

But the string username = (string) line gives me errors about Can't convert XElement to string.  If just want to get the first Login I can do it using root.Descendents, but I'd like to be able to call out any Login name I want just by type.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, you are trying to cast an IEnumerable to a string. Try using .First to get the first Login element instead:

```
string username = root.Elements("Username")
                      .First(el => (string)el.Attribute("type") == type)
                      .Element("Login")
                      .Value;
```

One other thing to watch for. In your examples, you use the uppercase T on Attribute("Type"), but it is lower cased in the XML. XML like C# is case sensitive.

Comment: Very cool, I didn't know you could write it like this.  I tried this example and on the line for root.Elements("Username") I get: Sequence contains no matching element.  I'm not familiar enough with the error messages to know what is wrong.

Comment: That error indicates that one of the steps didn't return any results and thus the following method couldn't be evaluated properly. Try testing this by checking each method to make sure that they return the results you are expecting. Also, make sure that there isn't an XML Namespace that you forgot to mention as 95% of the LINQ to XML errors with no results returned are caused by a missing namespace declaration in the query. Third, make sure `UserName` and `Login` are actually capitalized in your XML source.

Comment: I didn't realize that having one more level in the XML would make a difference, first time I've really done something with LINQ, but I ended up switching root.Elements to root.Descendents and that solved it.  Thanks a lot I don't think I would have gotten this far without the help...and I still have far to go in learning this stuff!

Comment: Yes, that's the difference between Element and Descendant. Element refers to one level down the tree whereas Descendant refers to any node below the current node. If you need more help with learning LINQ, I can recommend a good book ;-)

Comment: Please do, it never hurts to increase the reading list.  Thanks!

Comment: I was trying not to make a completely shameless plug, but since you asked: http://linqinaction.net/